# Is it possible to match string at the beginning of line, but only capture the end with regex?

Tags: regex, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have text that is something like this:

```
[G&]120948103471390857102349871[002]
[A&]512903451029349012390409232[002]
[2&]512903451029349012390409232[002]
```

I would like to match only the [002] of the first line that begins with [G&], but nothing else.

It is to be used on "syntax match" for vim syntax highlighting.

Comment: This is possible, of course. What language are you using and do you examine your text line by line or as a big multiline string?

Comment: It is for vim syntax highlighting, I am trying to use on "syntax match"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling longer I discovered that vim regex has a different lookahead/lookbehind.

Here it is:

```
\(G&.*\)\@<=\(\[\d\d\d\]$\)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick for you:

```
\[G&].*(\[.*])
```

[Here's](https://regex101.com/r/byqdxp/1) a demo.

"[002]" bit will be available in the first capture group of the regular expression.

Explaining each term in the regular expression in turn:

- `\[G&]` - we need to escape the opening `[` because it's a special character in regular expressions, then we match the character `G` followed by the `&` and `]` characters.
- `.*` - zero or more of any other characters.
- `(\[.*])` - we match an opening square bracket (again escaped) `\[` followed by zero or more of any other characters `.*` followed by the closing square brancket `]`.  This is we surrounded by parenthesise to indicate that we want to [capture a group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for a lookahead

```
^(?=\[G&\]).+(\[\d+\])\s*$
```

See [**a working demo**](https://regex101.com/r/5ZLANU/1/) on regex101.com. Additionally, you have trailing spaces in your demo string, are they intended?

Comment: not intended, it is for vim syntax highlighting, it goes something like "syntax match Type 'regex pattern here'", I am not able to use your solution there.